# Development Environment for mobile debug

Tags: android, xamarin, virtual-machine, adb

I currently working on a Xamarin .NET Core application, to debug my entire application, I use a VM with 32Gb to run back-end, web-service and web client to debug end to end.

But I want to debug my Xamarin app too. I can't debug over wifi, because the hotspot isn't accessible. I checked solution to plug directly on the cluster where my VM is hosted, however it is really convenient.

Hypervisor is an Esxi.

It's possible to route ADB flux from a physical device through a RDP connected VM ?

[image: Schema]

Comment: RDP client has the ability to forward USB devices to the server. Unfortunately this ability is if I remember correctly limited to certain USB classes therefore I assume the ADB USB device can't be forwarded. But ADB has the option for being connected via IP instead of USB. Search for adb over WiFi. Note that adb is a plain text protocol like telnet. For forwarding it to the VM wrap it in a secure transport like VPN.

Comment: Yes I tried to forward USB, directly in the RDP options on Windows but it never worked, like you say.

Comment: I can't use wifi because it is not on the same network..

Comment: It seems like the RDP connection can be used as tunnel. Check out the rdp2tcp Project. And the same WiFi is no problem, it is just a TCP connection. TCP can be just forwarded.

Comment: I will look into it! Thank you !

Comment: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2960949

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer**

We found a [software](https://www.incentivespro.com/usb-redirector-rdp.html) that bind USB over RDP on Windows, unfortunately, the software licence is not free but has a free trial period.

You need to install the workstation side on your physical computer, and the server side on your VM.

If someone find a opensource alternative working well as this client, he can share it here.